# generating ArrayController as sub-controllers of an ObjectController

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a model `post` linked to another model `comment` with a `hasMany` relationship on `comments` attribute of the `post` model.

I created a `post` `ObjectController` and a `comments` `ArrayController`. Normally in my `post` controller, since it'll act as a proxy, I'll have access to the `comments` property reflecting `comments` attribute in the `post` model. I want to define this property so that it'll use my `comments` controller, but **without the use of `Route#generateController` and without the use of `{{render...}}` from a template**.

In brief, I want to have `comments` property in `post` controller to be an instance of my `comments` controller, created directly from the `post` controller.

I could do like this:

```
import CommentsController from 'app/controllers/comments';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  comments: (function() {
    return CommentsController.create({model: this.get('model.comments')});
  }).property('model.comments').readOnly()
});
```

But then I loose the `container`, `store` and `parentController` from within this new `CommentsController` instance.

I could define those properties myself when creating the new controller, but **isn't there a best way to do this?**

*(keeping in mind that none of the `post` or `comments` controller instances will be the singleton, they'll be new independent instances)*

---

**UPDATE**:

I choose the example of `post`/`comments` as it is the common well known linking between 2 models. My use-case is `log`/`log-frame` where `log` is a model containing `client`, `project` and `frames`, this last one being a `hasMany` to `log-frames` which is my concern here.

In the model I have `startAt`, `endAt` and `duration`. The `endAt` can be `null`, in which case it means that this log time frame isn't closed and the `endAt` has to be replaced with `now`. The `duration` is not an attribute in the model, and is computed thanks to `startAt` and `endAt`. But I want to keep my models with no logic in them, and place this `endAt` and `duration` in a `log-frame` controller. Then I'd have a `log-frames` controller handling an array of `log-frame` and handling the sum of each duration, the minimum start and end, ... thanks to an `itemController` being `log-frame`. Then the `log` controller would be the one holding a `log` record and the one which would have to create that `log-frames` controller to hold the `log.frames` attribute being the list of `log-frames`.

If the way to do this is to move every computed property in the models instead of the controllers, then I'll do this, but I thought it was not good practice to place too much logic in the models apart from validation and such.

Comment: Ember's job is to combine controllers, routes, models and templates.  The fact that you're trying to handle some aspect of this yourself is probably an indicator that you're doing it wrong.  If you shared your use case and described why you think this is the solution you may get better results.

Answer (score 0):

Use render in your template, that will wrap your model in the controller specified by the first argument (it will also use the template specified).

#### Post controller

This is no longer necessary, unless you want to keep the collection reference read only

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

#### Using render in the template

```
{{render 'comments' comments}}
```

Using a controller arbitrarily in your code and manually creating instances of the controller (out of the scope of the controller/view logic) is also an anti-pattern.

Comment: I know about this, but as I said: "without the use of `Route#generateController` and without the use of `{{render...}}` from a template"

Comment: I added a comment at the end, the pattern you're attempting to use would be considered an anti pattern, the way around it would be to use the container to obtain an instance.  Here's how you'd do it, but I'm not putting it in the answer because it's a definite anti-pattern: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/direg/1/edit

Comment: Additionally if you believe you're going to reuse the properties, make them into a mixin and add the mixin to the model.

Comment: Ok so adding those computed properties directly to the model is not an anti-pattern then right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm including a answer here using a `Mixin` for reference, as suggested by @Kingpin2k:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var CircleMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    circumference: function() {
        return this.get('radius')*2*Math.PI;
    }.property('radius'),
    area: function() {
        var radius= this.get('radius');
        return radius*radius*Math.PI;
    }.property('radius')
});
```

#### Then you could use the mixin in `Controller`s:

```
var BigCircleController= Ember.ObjectController.extend(CircleMixin, {
    // ... etc
});

var LittleCircleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(CircleMixin, {
    // ... etc
}
```

#### Or you could use it in a `Model`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
var CircleModel = DS.Model.extend(CircleMixin, {
    // ... etc.
});
```

All of them would respond to the request for the `area` property.

Comment: Well, thanks but here appart from using a mixin in the model we are going far from my original question. So I'd take this as an answer: "put the logic in the model somehow" and I'll not do it with a mixin because then if it's on the model I do not need to set those properties anywhere else since the controllers will proxy them ;-)

Comment: Not always.  A common pattern for me is to have a `new` route that needs those computed properties.  However, it is easiest to create a model object of `{}` for the new route and then use it in the action handler to create a new record when saving.  If you'd like to use the computed properties, you can't on the temporary object, but you can if you use the sharable mixin technique.  You have more flexibility in having those properties that will work with any `Ember.Object`.

Comment: And yes, answers will be far from your question, because it is not a normal pattern for properties to be instances of `Controller`.  I'll quote Kingpin2k again in case you missed it: "Using a controller arbitrarily in your code and manually creating instances of the controller (out of the scope of the controller/view logic) is also an anti-pattern."

Comment: Ok, so to resume, it's an anti-pattern to define those computed properties on the controller and they should be defined in the model instead (thru a mixin or directly). Thanks! I'd love to mark an answer as accepted but both does not really answer the question, so if you want to create a new answer resuming this I'd be happy to mark it as accepted ;-)